# Bright flash in Opera when switching pages

Tags: html, css, opera

Whenever I switch pages in a website I'm working on now, I get a bright flash of white on every page load. I assume it's caused by white default browser background, and it's very annoying and looks horrible. This doesn't seem to happen on other pages or in other browsers though.

Is there something about my stylesheet or anything I use on the page which which causes this flash? Anything I can do to prevent it?

The website is available at http://www.triangelos.no, and I'm using Opera 11.52.

Comment: i cant reproduce this on win7

Comment: I see the flash on IE9, FF and Chrome, too.

Comment: @Rob, how annoying... oh well.. maybe I'll just have to try not caring, hehe.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this happens because it is reloading the background each time.

You can use mod_expires for Apache for this.
For example, you can put this in your .htaccess:

```
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 months"
```

As you can see you can set a different expiring time for different types of files, depending on what you use as the background you can use css or one of the image types.
You can also set a default expiring time for all files:

```
ExpiresDefault "access plus 30 days"
```

For more information: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_expires.html

Remember that you need to have mod_expires enabled in Apache for this.

**EDIT:** I only get this when I press 'Musikk' and go to the http://music.triangelos.no subdomain. I think this is impossible to fix since you are switching domains and loading other files. If you want to prevent this you should probably change it into http://triangelos.no/music or something like that.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I also assume is happening, but the weird thing is that I have no background other than #222. Maybe it's the stylesheet which causes the reloading flash since I haven't enabled exipres on that yet? Either way it doesn't happen on my other browsers... maybe I'll take a cache/cookie clean dance to see if that fixes anything...

Comment: Yes you could try caching the stylesheet, but as I said in my EDIT I doubt this will work while changing domains.

Comment: That's true. Weird thing is that I don't seem to get that flash when changing the domain, hehe. Maybe it's just my particular browser install which acts in inverse :p